# Validate json schema in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, yii

I have following json pattern

```
{"property":[{"id":"1","name":"Property 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Property 2"}]}
```

How can i validate json schema? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Programatically, or will a linter such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) suffice?

Comment: https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema

Comment: Do you want to verify the syntax or the content (property names and types)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode($string);` to convert the JSON string into native PHP. If `NULL` is returned the string cannot be decoded. You can then use `json_last_error()` to get the error code, which may be helpful.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: For strict JSON validation, you must use `is_object($result) || is_array($result)`. Simple values like strings or numbers are allowed by `json_decode()` and many other parsers but are not strictly valid JSON. For looser validation checking for `NULL` is fine.